# How to refresh rows of Table?

Tags: android

My simple question is 
Can we Refresh our table after inserting a new row in android application.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a `ListView` the way to do it is to call the `notifyDataSetChanged` function.

if you're not using ListView, now would be the time to change your implementation...

Comment: No, I am not using ListView,i have mentioned in my question.Please answer my question.

Comment: if you are not using ListView you should. that is the right way of doing this.